# Change the date of an image

Tags: android

How can I change the date in image's MetaData?

Example : upload image from storage to app and change metadata ( date and time ) and save it with new date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ExifInterface` to save the attributes for the file,

You can do like this,

```
ExifInterface source = new ExifInterface(sourcePath);
source.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_DATETIME_ORIGINAL, "[Date here]");
source.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_DATETIME, "[Date here]");
source.saveAttributes();
```

For a complete list of the attribute tags, you can refer `android.media.ExifInterface`

Comment: Didn't know this existed in vanilla Android. Nice find!